# How to reverse RGB array to BGR array in tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

There is a RGB image with [512,512,3] shape ,now I want to reverse the array in BGR  not in RGB,how to do it in tensorflow.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.reverse` along the channel axis

```
tf.reverse(tensor, -1)
```

One can also use `tf.unstack` and `tf.stack`. That can be useful if one wants to reverse the image channel in any order

```
temp = tf.unstack(tensor, axis)
tf.stack([temp[2], temp[1], temp[0]], axis)
```

```js
const x = tf.tensor3d([1, 2 , 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7, 8], [2, 2, 2]);

const axis = 2;
// tf.reverse
x.reverse(axis).print();

// tf.stack and tf.unstack
const temp = tf.unstack(x, axis)
tf.stack([temp[1], temp[0]], 2).print()

// tf.split and tf.concat
const temp1 = tf.split(x, 2, 2)
tf.concat([temp1[1], temp1[0]], 2).print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```